# ipython dead kernel and cannot be restarted, what can i do?

Tags: r, jupyter, jupyter-irkernel

When I try to open r file through jupyter notebook shell, the kernel cannot start and it shows:

```
The kernel has died, and the automatic restart has failed. 
It is possible the kernel cannot be restarted. 
If you are not able to restart the kernel, you will still be able to save the notebook,
 but running code will no longer work until the notebook is reopened.
```

While the terminal shows:

```
*** caught segfault ***
address 0x18, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
 2: library.dynam(lib, package, package.lib)
 3: loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]])
 4: namespaceImport(ns, loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()),     versionCheck = vI[[i]]), from = package)
 5: loadNamespace(name)
 6: doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler)
 7: tryCatchOne(expr, names, parentenv, handlers[[1L]])
 8: tryCatchList(expr, classes, parentenv, handlers)
 9: tryCatch(loadNamespace(name), error = function(e) stop(e))
10: getNamespace(ns)
11: asNamespace(ns)
12: getExportedValue(pkg, name)
13: IRkernel::main
aborting ...
```

I use anaconda3 on MAC OS, and use conda -install -c r r-essentials to install the r packages. 
After several attempts to reinstall ipython, it still does not work!
Thanks in advance for your attention and help.

Comment: Did you search Google for this error?  A lot of results come up, all related to Python configuration.

Comment: Find some similar problems, but not the same, and no common solution.

Comment: All of the hits reference this "notebook".  Seems you should start there.

Comment: Faced a similar issue it was due to zmq installation path. Could you try reinstalling rzmq using conda install  rzmq

Answer (score 0):

Start R and then type

install.packages("rzmq", dependencies=TRUE, repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')